# How to dual boot windows 7 with Ubuntu installed first?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

i'm running ubuntu 15.04, but i want to play  some games like battlefield 2 or command and conquer generals, but i don't think that's possible on ubuntu (or using a windows on virtual machine).

So please guys, how to i install windows 7 dual boot with ubuntu install first, if it has something to do with partitioning please more details because i'm new to this os, the partitioning here seems nothing like windows,thanks in advance :p

Comment: You can't... Even if you do manage to partition correctly (GParted is a good tool for that btw) Windows will always simply overwrite EVERYTHING. Also, have you ever tried Minecraft?

Comment: Is Ubuntu booting in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And is drive partitioned in gpt or MBR(msdos)? Post this: `sudo parted -l` Windows only installs to gpt partitioned drives with UEFI and to MBR drives with BIOS. And Windows 7 default install is BIOS, but you can copy to flash drive & edit to make it an UEFI installer. If BIOS, Windows must be installed to a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag(active partition in Windows speak).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing_Windows_After_Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Even though It's Willem said you can't you can. First, before I respond, I need to know: Do you have multiple hard drives, or at least 1 TB of space. If not, it would not be smart to follow through doing this. If you do...

```
    sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then open gparted in your search bar and create a new partition, leaving at least 500 GB for the windows installation. Then once you have that partition made..

```
    sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

You don't have to use gedit, I just like the simplicity.
You should see a line at the bottom that looks like this:

```
 /dev/sda1       /home           ext4    defaults        0       1
```

Copy that information from your new partition, and make that line. Then save, and exit.

Finally do

```
   mount -a
```

Then **SHUTDOWN. DO NOT REBOOT.**
Obviously turn your computer back on. Login, and do

```
    df
```

You should now see a new drive, mounted on whatever file. You now have this partition to use for a Windows Installation. There you go!

Comment: That's in case the user will not have other issues like Uefi or problems with the grub,  which will complex the answer much more.

Comment: Yes, very true, they may need to edit UEFI, which isn't that hard, and grub rarely, and mostly NEVER has problems.

Comment: It is not as easy.  New computers has the safe Uefi which will difficult to do this process,  although as you said,  this is possible!!!

Comment: Yep, and Actually, yes it can be complicated depending on your motherboard, but on mine (ASUS Z787 Extreme4) You just need to hit F2 during boot, and you can edit anything, so it was simple.

Comment: Yeahh,  it sounds  it was an easy step.  On the other hand when I did it in mine I was trying and finding and so on...  So many days to find the solution  which was deactivating the safe boot inside the operative system because in the BIOS didn't appear. :)

Comment: That sucks, sounds pretty bad